# Javascript, Jquery Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am going crazy with `.getjson`. I am trying to get data from a Wikipedia API using `.getjson` and it works fine. Let's say the Wikipedia API returns 10 selections, and before looping over each selection, I am trying to find the length of array in a for loop. The data is not available yet from the '.getjson'.

[Here](https://codepen.io/uaefame/pen/PWERxM?editors=1011) is my work in codepen. Look at `console.log(sp.length);` and `sp.length` in the for loop. They should give similar data, but one of them is undefined and other is working fine.

Here is my JS code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {


var api_wiki="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&titles=Main+Page&srsearch=cat&srwhat=text&callback=?";
var sp;

$.getJSON(api_wiki,function(data){
  sp=data.query.search;
 // console.log(sp.length);
}); //End of getJSON

for (var i=0;i<sp.length;i++){

} 


});//End of get ready
```

Why does `console.log` give two different answers even though they both refer to the same variable? One is undefined and the other is working fine.
I edited the question so that it only reflect the problem facing.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you removed all code that does not have anything to do with the problem.. http://sscce.org/   There's way too much going on that I don't think many people are wanting to look trough. Just show us in a couple of lines the faulty behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ask javascript to use data it doesn't have yet. You need to wait for the data to arrive. Try putting the for loop inside a function and calling the function in the onReady event of the getJSON:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


var api_wiki="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&titles=Main+Page&srsearch=cat&srwhat=text&callback=?";
var sp;

$.getJSON(api_wiki,function(data){
  sp=data.query.search;
  console.log(sp.length);
  workWithTheData(sp);
}); //End of getJSON

function workWithTheData(sp){
    for (var i=0;i<sp.length;i++){
      console.log(sp[i]);
    } 
 }


});//End of get ready
```